# In Unity, how to build and play a WebGL project and play it on an Android device?

Tags: android, build, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'm trying to build a WebGL Unity game for Android and iOS devices but I'm not sure how. I can run the game fine on PC because the **Build & Play** option from the **Build Settings** does this automatically for me. But what if I want to playtest the game on an Android device?

For clarification, I am not looking to create an Android build (i.e. an APK file). I'm attempting to create a WebGL build and playtest this WebGL build on an Android device's web browser.

Comment: Why do you not want to export Android and iOS builds from Unity?

Comment: The game is to be part of a suite of multiple (unity) games launched from a website to be played on mobile devices, so it's a technical requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using WebGL export on mobile devices in windows, install IIS. 
In Linux, use Apache to create a web server and upload the exported folder to the www root folder of the web server.
Then call your **ip:port/yourSiteName** in a mobile browser.

Check this [link](https://livierickson.com/blog/configuring-iis-for-running-unity-exported-webgl-games/) for a walkthrough of uploading in IIS

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this isn't what I need. I don't want to create an Android build, I want to create a WebGL build and test it on an Android device's web browser.

Answer (score 2):

When WebGL build's selected Unity asks where to save it. In the selected location a directory with selected name will be created. For example, I've for the lack of imagination called mine `webgl` and this's what I've got:

[image]

If you make content of this directory available via HTTP (or put it to a web server), you can open your game with any WebGL-enabled device.

Answer (score 1):

So, I can tell you from experience, Unity WebGL games work pretty poorly on mobile devices.

But if you still want to try it, I run a website for hosting Unity WebGL games at https://simmer.io. To upload you drag and drop the WebGLBuild folder onto the website.

For local development, I like this tool for exposing a local web server to the internet: https://ngrok.com/. Or you can host the game on any web hosting service. Here's how to do it on AWS: https://hackernoon.com/how-i-built-and-deployed-a-webgl-game-to-a-new-website-in-35m-15b2e8339c31